# Return XML from Web Api Controller

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How to specify return xml from web api controller?In one browser data opens as XML,in other as JSON.

**Edit**

Here is my action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<MagazineMeta> GetLastUploadPdfMeta(int count)
    {
       List<MagazineMeta> metas = _metaRepository
                 .GetAll()
                 .OrderBy(e => e.TimeAdd)
                 .Take(count)
                 .ToList();

       return metas;
    }
```

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far?

Comment: is there any attribute that specifyes return data format?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The ASP.NET WebAPI returns the data in the format requested by the caller. Obviously one browser requested it as XML, the other as JSON.

Comment: @NET, yes.  Look at HTTP Accept header.  "application/xml" and "application/json" are two common values you will see when asking for xml and json respectively from a web api.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add these 2 lines to the end of Application_Start in Global.asax.cs:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
```

**EDIT:**
As @YishaiGalatzer pointed out, this is rather quick & dirty workaround to achieve what was originally asked in question. To get desired response format include appropriate Accept header  in request (in context of this question, "application/xml")

Comment: This is a really bad general practice. This way you took out Json completely out of the picture. It's a big hammer. Web API has content negotiation support and this just shuts it down. See this article on how to: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kiranchalla/archive/2012/02/25/content-negotiation-in-asp-net-mvc4-web-api-beta-part-1.aspx

Comment: According to the question, NET always wanted to return XML, regardless of headers, so why the downvote?

Comment: Because the practice is wrong, this is a big hammer and you are showing a rather bad example. First the user might want to return the right format per the requester, which he wasn't so clear in the question. Second there is a way to do it cleanly such that it doesn't affect other areas in the app. I would have shown both answers rather than a quick and dirty way to fix it. (cannot take out the down vote, unless the answer is editted)

Comment: Yes its true, its bad practice but as I said, the answer was given for the original question which harshly took JSON out of the picture.I edited the answer and added details that were sorted out in comments of question. Please feel free to suggest better explanation and I shall edit it further. Regards!

Comment: Thanks! Checkout the blog from Kiran Challa on my first comment, on how this can also be achieved per action.

Comment: Nice solution with MediaTypeHeaderValue (local if needed so it does not have global effect).

Answer (score 1):

To make response serialize you need one more line

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

And for others who want to enforce json instead, call this :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```